# Add 2nd column when column matches in str.contains

Tags: python, pandas

I want to search through the `searchList` and check if column `text` `str.contains` one or more of each `searchWord`. If I get a match I want to append the data to `masterdf` which is easily accomplished as seen below. But I also want to add a new column with `searchWord` so that I know which `text` matched with what. This code below fills the column `searchWord` with the latest search that matched.

```
masterdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=['doc_id','text',])

for searchWord in searchList:
    search = jsons_data[jsons_data['text'].str.contains(searchWord)]
    if len(search) > 0:
        masterdf = masterdf.append(search)
        masterdf['searchWord'] = searchWord
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are after.

Let's setup up example data:

```
tt = '''I want to search through the. searchList and check if column text str.contains one or more of each searchWord. If I get a match I want to append the data to masterdf which is easily accomplished as seen below. But I also want to add a new column with searchWord so that I know which text matched with what. This code below fills the column searchWord with the. latest search that matched'''
text_col = tt.split('.')
id_col = range(len(text_col))
jsons_data = pd.DataFrame({'doc_id':id_col,'text':text_col})

searchList = ['code','fills', 'But','also','want']
```

The example `jsons_data` is

```
    doc_id  text
0   0       I want to search through the
1   1       searchList and check if column text str
2   2       contains one or more of each searchWord
3   3       If I get a match I want to append the data to...
4   4       But I also want to add a new column with sear...
5   5       This code below fills the column searchWord w...
6   6       latest search that matched
```

Modifying your code with `search['searchWord'] = searchWord` we get:

```
masterdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=['doc_id','text','searchWord'])

for searchWord in searchList:
    search = jsons_data[jsons_data['text'].str.contains(searchWord)]
    if len(search) > 0:
        search['searchWord'] = searchWord
        masterdf = masterdf.append(search)
```

And `masterdf` is

```
doc_id  text                                                searchWord
5   5.0 This code below fills the column searchWord w...    code
5   5.0 This code below fills the column searchWord w...    fills
4   4.0 But I also want to add a new column with sear...    But
4   4.0 But I also want to add a new column with sear...    also
0   0.0 I want to search through the                        want
3   3.0 If I get a match I want to append the data to...    want
4   4.0 But I also want to add a new column with sear...    want
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use vectorized (no looping) approach:

```
In [84]: df
Out[84]:
   doc_id                                                                                                text
0       0                                                                        I want to search through the
1       1                                                             searchList and check if column text str
2       2                                                             contains one or more of each searchWord
3       3   If I get a match I want to append the data to masterdf which is easily accomplished as seen below
4       4     But I also want to add a new column with searchWord so that I know which text matched with what
5       5                                                This code below fills the column searchWord with the
6       6                                                                          latest search that matched

In [85]: searchList = ['code', 'fills', 'but', 'also', 'want']

In [86]: words_re = '{}'.format('|'.join(searchList).lower())

In [87]: words_re
Out[87]: 'code|fills|but|also|want'

In [88]: masterdf = df[df.text.str.contains('(?:{})'.format(words_re))].copy()

In [89]: masterdf['searchWord'] = masterdf.text.str.findall('({})'.format(words_re)).str.join('|')

In [90]: masterdf
Out[90]:
   doc_id                                                                                                text  searchWord
0       0                                                                        I want to search through the        want
3       3   If I get a match I want to append the data to masterdf which is easily accomplished as seen below        want
4       4     But I also want to add a new column with searchWord so that I know which text matched with what   also|want
5       5                                                This code below fills the column searchWord with the  code|fills
```

Comment: This looks really nice. Why is this better than looping? And is there a "clearer"/more correct way of thinking about this problem, than "add column when match..."?

Comment: @user3471881, because for bigger (1000+) data sets vectorized solutions usually order(s) of magnitude faster compared to "looping" solutions